# How to remove double quotes in python?

Tags: python, csv

When i try to create a new csv file and add rows to it, it add '"' to the start and end of each row. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Post some code please!!!

Comment: Are you passing it a single string you've built rather than a list of values?

Comment: writer = csv.writer(open("/filepath/temp.csv",'w'))  This is the line of code that i am using

Comment: no i am passing a list of values

Answer (score 3):

Create your csv writer passing in [this kwarg](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE):

```
csv.writer(fileobj, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Comment: Yeah i tried this also but it keeps on giving exception, the exception says delimitter cannot be left blank, i tried adding delimitter and quotechar also but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `csv` library, you could simply output the file as such:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> x = map(str,x)
>>> with open('out.csv','w') as fout:
...     fout.write(','.join(x))
... 
>>> with open('out.csv','r') as fin:
...     print fin.read().split(',')
... 
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Comment: I need to add a list of values, i feel it wont work for feeding list of values

Comment: don't feel, just try. I will work, because csv is simply concatanating elements in list with commas so equivalent to outputing  `','.join(alist)`